# How do I define the callback in the Async library's "Each" function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

In Caolan's [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) library, the documentation says that the `each` function:

> Applies the function iteratee to each item in arr, in parallel. The iteratee is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when it has finished.

This example is given:

```
async.each(arr, iteraree, function(err){
    //Do stuff
});
```

My question is how is the "callback", in this case `iteraree`, defined?  How do you declare which callback function you would like called when it has finished?

If you were able to define functions as a parameter I could see it working but you can't (i.e):

```
async.each(openFiles, function (item, function () {console.log("done")}), function(err){
  //Do stuff
});
```

But how could I define that callback not inline?

If I do something like

```
var iteraree = function (item, callback) {};
```

And passed in `iteraree` I still do not see where I would be able to define the behavior of `callback`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I still do not see where I would be able to define the behavior of `callback`.

You don't. `callback` is just a parameter. `async.each` calls `iteratee` and passes a value for `callback`. It's your responsibility to *call* `callback` when you are done. This lets `async.each` know that it can continue to the next iteration.

---

`function (item, function () {console.log("done")})` is invalid JavaScript btw. You cannot have a function definition in place of a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

That iteratee function doesn't have the signature you think it does. It looks like this:

```
async.each(openFiles, function (item, cb){
       console.log(item);
       cb();   
    }, function(err){
      //Do stuff
 });
```

It receives each item and a callback function from asynchronous.each() that has to be called when you finish whatever you are doing. You don't provide the callback.

So if you are using a named function it's just:

```
 function foo (item, cb){
       console.log(item);
       cb();   
    }

async.each(openFiles, foo, function(err){
      //Do stuff
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of example from their docs with added comments

```
//I personally prefer to define it as anonymous function, because it is easier to see that this function will be the one iterated
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

    callback(); //this is just like calling the next item to iterate

}, then);

//this gets called after all the items are iterated or an error is raised
function then(err){
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
}
```